# jQuery mouse position on mousedown() without mousemove()

Tags: jquery

Can I get cursor position at `mousedown(event)` event, without using `mousemove(event)` continuously (thus waisting resources)? `event.pageX` returns `NaN` on `mousedown`

Comment: It which browser? It's fine for me in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/JsaPG/3/

Comment: @James: works, bug in my code, sorry for troubling : )

Comment: No problem, I thought that might be the case!

Comment: @Jakub, can you provide an answer? then others can learn from your mistake. This isn't just a Q&A site, but also a reference of sorts :)

Comment: @James: your answer is correct, if you paste the answer, I will accept it, thx

Comment: @Jakub - My "answer" isn't really an answer (which is why I posted it as a comment). It would probably be more helpful to other users who come across this page if you post a description of what the problem was and how you fixed it. You can post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On behalf of James:

from - http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/JsaPG/3/

```
<input type="button" id="test" value="click" style="width:200px" />

$("#test").mousedown(function(e) {
   console.log(e.pageX); 
});
```